# Drupal view not using css classes

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, block

I have a Drupal JSON view. Views format is table. Then I have 3 blocks in the header of the view. One of these block contains a form and that block is empty in some cases. When the block is empty the view wont use the views CSS classes on the views table. It just uses them on the blocks. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this.

The CSS classes I'm using are *table table-striped full sticky-enabled*

I'm using a custom theme on my site.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi have a look at this

 body    
{
 font:16px Calibri;
}
table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
 td {
        margin:0;
        border:3px solid grey;
        border-top-width:0px;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        overflow-x:scroll;  
        margin-left:5em;
        overflow-y:visible;
        padding-bottom:1px;
    }
    .headcol {
        position:absolute;
        width:5em;
        left:0;
        top:auto;
        border-right: 0px none black;
        border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
        margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
    }
    .headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
    .long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }
```